# UVA(769) :critical links getting wrong answer

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I am solving [Critical links](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=9&page=show_problem&problem=737) problem on UVA.The problem is about finding the bridges in the Graph.I used the same [algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bridge-in-a-graph/) here.But I am continuously getting wrong answer.
Please suggest what's wrong with my code.

```
//Bridges in a Graphs
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
#include<utility>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 205
int parent[MAX],timer=0,low[MAX],disc[MAX];
bool vis[MAX];
vector<pair<int,int> >st;
vector<vector<int> >G(MAX);
bool cmp(const pair<int,int> a,pair<int,int> b)
{
    if(a.first==a.second)
    return a.second<b.second;
    else
    return a.first<b.first;
}
void reset()
{
    st.clear();
    memset(parent,-1,sizeof parent);
    memset(vis,false,sizeof vis);
    for(int i=0;i<=MAX;i++)
    G[i].clear();
}
void dfs(int u)
{   
    vis[u]=true;
    disc[u]=low[u]=timer++;
    for(int i=0;i<G[u].size();i++)
    {
        int v=G[u][i];
        if(!vis[v])
        {
            parent[v]=u;
            dfs(v);
            low[u]=min(low[u],low[v]);
            if(low[v]>low[u])
            st.push_back(make_pair(min(u,v),max(u,v)));
        }
        else if(v!=parent[u])
            low[u]=min(low[u],disc[v]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n,t=0;

    while(cin>>n)
    {
        reset();
        if(t>0)
        cout<<endl;
        if(n==0)
        {
            cout<<"0"<<" critical links\n";break;
        }
        int node,count;

        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d (%d)",&node,&count);
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                int x;
                scanf("%d",&x);
                G[node].push_back(x);
                G[x].push_back(node);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(!vis[i])
            dfs(i);
        }
        sort(st.begin(),st.end(),cmp);
        cout<<st.size()<<" critical links\n";

        for(int i=0;i<st.size();i++)
        cout<<st[i].first<<" - "<<st[i].second<<endl;
        t++;

    }
}
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mix C I/O (`scanf` etc) with C++ I/O (`cin >>` etc).

Comment: Your ordering, `cmp`, doesn't satisfy the requirements for `std::sort`.

Comment: @molbdnilo You could be a bit more helpful than that.  The code says `if(a.first==a.second)` where obviously the intent was `if(a.first==b.first)`.  The OP might easily stare at the code as written but see the code as intended and never understand your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it,little bit flaw in `std::sort` cmp function and it is

```
bool cmp(const pair<int,int> a,pair<int,int> b)
{
    if(a.first==b.first)
    return a.second<b.second;
    else
    return a.first<b.first;
}
```

also in dfs function `low[v]>disc[u]` instead of `low[v]>low[u]`.